# Showing latest product add

Tags: magento-1.8, products

I just installed Magento with custom free template ( Eros ). what I trying now is to add latest or just list of products to the homepage. 
On the CMS->Pages->Home page-> Design `(which I think that doesn't work because if I delete everything from there nothing change on the frontend)` has this which I think is responsible for this action:

```
 <block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
 </block>
```

Then in content I've put this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="product_homepage" template="catalog/product/new.phtml"}}
```

And there si nothing on the page.

EDIT:
In content of home-page also is this which is working.

```
{{block type="customblocks/customblock" alias="root" template="customblocks/customblock.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are missing reference name. use `<reference name="content">` for show new products at content area.

```
<reference name="content">
<block type="catalog/product_new" name="home.catalog.product.new" alias="product_new" template="catalog/product/new.phtml" after="cms_page">
        <action method="addPriceBlockType">
            <type>bundle</type>
            <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
            <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
        </action>
 </block>
```